# Create a clickable link in php from sql results

Tags: php

I am trying to make the results from mysql results clickable links in php. I am new to php and please help.

```
<?php mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "pass") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("Branches") or die(mysql_error());
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items order by ID desc Limit 5") or die(mysql_error());
while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {
    echo $info['title'];
    echo " <br>";
    echo $info['descr'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
} ?>
```

Comment: you can do something like `echo '<a href="'.$info['descr'].'">bla link</a>';` whats the problem ?

Comment: Seems like, you wanna show data from database on link click. ??

Answer (score 1):

```
while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {
    echo '<a href="somefile.php?id='.$info['ID'].'">'.$info['title'].'</a>';
    echo " <br>";
    echo $info['descr'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Then in `somefile.php`, use `$_GET` to capture the id and show the results

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
// pull info from db based on $id
$sql = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM items WHERE ID = "'.$id.'"');
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: Thanks Asprin, The clickable link worked briliantly but I am now strugling with pulling a field 'details' from the items table corresponding with the 'id'.  I tried the following code but it not working, where am I going wrong? '<?php  

 $id = $_GET['id'];
// pull info from db based on $id
$sql = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE ID = '".$id."'";

while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    echo $info ['Title'];
 echo $info ['Details'];
 " <br>";

}?>'

Comment: The message from the browser is: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\news\article.php on line 7

Comment: @Ucz that error - `Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource ...` is caused because you are using `$sql` which is your sql string without `mysql_query()`. Change it to - `$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE ID = '".$id."'");`

Comment: Yep! @Sean got it spot on. Wonder how I missed that

Comment: Thanks guys, you r life servers. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

just use anchor tag like this

```
while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {
    echo "<a href =\"$info[title]\">".$info['title'];. "</a>";
}
```

Comment: let op replay my comment first ..i am telling same ... question is vague

Answer (score 0):

`echo '<a href="php page which you want to display on click">$info['descr']</a>'`

Comment: let op replay my comment first ..i am telling same ... question is vague